# Tensorflow using Python programming

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm really newbie in python programming specially in tensorflow concept, I already installed tensorflow in my PC, But when I make a simple program to execute "Hello Tensorflow" there is something annoyed me, the out put always appear " b' " like this picture.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCtH6.png)
and my source code like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant("Hello, TensorFlow!")
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

anybody may help me to solve this problem please?
I'm sorry for my bad english anyway.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 2):

In python 3 there are two types of strings.

1. byte strings
2. strings

byte strings are array of characters which are prefixed by `b'`. In order to convert byte into string one needs to decode it. byte instances have method `decode` that will convert the byte to normal string. `decode` method expects encoding usually 'utf-8'.

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant("Hello, TensorFlow!")
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello).decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: i'm already used python 3.5.2, and my problem already solved when i add .decode("utf-8")
Thanks